# Magento 2.1.1 Check Component Dependency

Tags: magento2, php, upgrade

I am getting Check Component Dependency which is showing many issues. See below.
But.. my PHP version on the webhosting is 7.0 and in the Magento Setup Pgae showing  5.6.19. how it comes?
Please advise.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Your CLI and webserver version of PHP are different. Please check if you can change the CLI version.